# Can't run empty Android app on Jetbrains Rider

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, rider

I can't run Android App with single empty activity neither on emulator nor on physical device. I get this error:

```
Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(487, 2): [null] C:\dev\ide\Microsoft Visual Studio 15.0\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(487,2): error : Value cannot be null.
C:\dev\ide\Microsoft Visual Studio 15.0\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(487,2): error : Parameter name: path1
```

Comment: We created issue [RIDER-5886](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-5886). Could you please provide us with details about your SDK there? Do you have Xamarin.Android SDK installed? Do you have several Android SDK installed? Have you tried to run this project using Xamarin Studio/Visual Studio?

Comment: Thank you for response Arseny. My SDK is up to date. I have Visual Studio 2017 with Xamarin. And it works without any problem, I have only one SDK which is shared between Android Studio, Visual Studio and Rider. I tried to open project created in Rider in Visual Studio but got incompatibility error. If you want further details feel free to ask.